# YoutubeAndroidPlayerApi giving PLAYER_VIEW_TOO_SMALL error on Samsung S4 after 1 second

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am trying to play a youtube video in my app. I am getting PLAYER_VIEW_TOO_SMALL error in onError() callback.

The problem is that it is working in all other phones but not working in Samsung S4.

Even through the size of my Youtube Player view is greater than 200dp x 110dp.

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: No. I am not working on this.

Comment: You mean you ignored the model S4 or you have decided not to youtube player or you managed to fix it but do not remember?

Comment: I was helping someone on this problem he faced. I don't know what happened later.